# Is there any significance to the file Code.gs? Best practices?

Tags: google-apps-script

Is the Code.gs file and/or filename special in any way? Is it expected to be used for any particular purposes, like initialization or UI setup or general utilities?

Comment: No.  You can put all of your functions in there or if you would like to organize them you can use appropriately named files at your own discretion. Note: all of the functions in a project have to have different names...even if they are in different files.

Comment: Officially, I don't know of any requirement to keep the code.gs file.  However, I always keep it, and only put the `onInstall()` and `onOpen()` functions in that file, and nothing else.  And I never create a gs file with a name that is alphabetically before "code."  I have no proof that it makes a difference, but if Apps Script is looking for those functions first, I want them to be at the front.

Answer (score 2):

It's just the default name for the file whenever you create a new Script, you can rename it as you wish and create others with whichever name you choose. As Cooper said, however, keep in mind not having duplicate functions, since these are declared across files.